# XML serialization related problem with XmlIgnore

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

When serializing a class I get an error if the XmlIgnore attribute is commented. When I uncomment the XmlIgnore attribute it works fine. Can anyone tell me why a property can't be serializable?

Comment: pro tip: whenever talking about an error, ***include the error details***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, it will tell you why very clearly in the exception - look in particular at the InnerException; however, to summarise:

For a custom type `SomeType` to be serializable via `XmlSerializer` (either as the root object or via a property, i.e. `public SomeType MemberName {get;set;}`)

- it must be `public`
- it must have a public parameterless constructor
- a few generic combinations may not be supported
- it must be *expected* (exposing data as `object` is a no-go, for example; subtypes of `SomeType` must be advertised in advance, typically via `[XmlInclude(...)]`)
- it must be concrete (non-`abstract`), or have concrete implementations defined via `[XmlInclude(...)]`

Using `[XmlIgnore]` removes the type from consideration, so types that are not xml-friendly can be avoided. You can also try `IXmlSerializable` for those cases